# Twilio programmable video using back camera of phone in selected devices?

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call, twilio-video

When I configured Twilio programmable video using following code:

```
Video.connect(token, {
      name: roomName,
      audio: true,
      logLevel: 'info',
      maxAudioBitrate: 16000,
      video: { frameRate: 30, width: 1260, height: 650, controls: false },
    })
```

In some of the devices such as Ipad tab or mobile phones, user is connecting to back camera instead of front camera of device.

Is there a way for us to specify the constraints to make sure Twilio video is always connecting to only front camera. Thanks!

Comment: @philnash could you help here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I wrote about [how to select cameras in JavaScript here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/choosing-cameras-javascript-mediadevices-api-html). If you are trying to ensure you select a user facing camera, then you want the [`facingMode` constraint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints/facingMode). Set `facingMode` to `user` and you will select user facing cameras on a system that supports it.

```
Video.connect(token, {
      name: roomName,
      audio: true,
      logLevel: 'info',
      maxAudioBitrate: 16000,
      video: {
        frameRate: 30,
        width: 1260,
        height: 650,
        facingMode: "user"
      },
    });
```

Note that I don't believe `controls` is a valid media constraint, so I have removed that from the code above.

Comment: Thanks for your response @philnash. Also, really appreciate you rectifying the wrong constraint. Really helpful.